# Ошибка в query SQLITE (Android приложение)

Tags: android, sqlite, запрос, android-sqlite, autocompletetextview

В SQLite создана БД со следующими таблицами:

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "DB";

    public static final String TABLE_DOWNL_OPERATION= "downloaded_operations";
    public static final String OPERATION_DOWNLOADED = "operation_downloaded";

    public static final String TABLE_WORKERS = "workers";
    public static final String WORKER_ID_KEY = "_worker_id";
    public static final String FIO_OF_WORKER = "fio_of_worker";
    public static final String DEPARTMENT_OF_WORKER = "department_of_worker";
    public static final String ORGANIZATION_OF_WORKER = "organization_of_worker";

    /**
     * Конструктор Хэлпера
     *
     * @param context - контекст нашего прилажения, в котором испольуется Хэлпер
     */
    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    /**
     * При создании базы данных - создаем таблицы operations,
     * workers, chronometragers, downloaded_positions
     *
     * @param db - непосредственно БД
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_WORKERS + " (" +
                WORKER_ID_KEY + " integer primary key," +
                FIO_OF_WORKER + " text unique not null," +
                DEPARTMENT_OF_WORKER + " text unique not null," +
                ORGANIZATION_OF_WORKER + " text unique not null" + ")");

        db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_DOWNL_OPERATION + " (" +
                OPERATION_DOWNLOADED + " text not null"+ ")");
    }

    /**
     * Метод при обновлении на новую версию таблицы. Удаляет старую БД. Создает новую с помощью
     *
     * @param db         - текущая БД
     * @param oldVersion - старая версия БД
     * @param newVersion - новая версия БД
     */
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("drop table if exists " + TABLE_OPERATIONS);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

Я хочу передать данные из таблицы TABLE_DOWNL_OPERATION в автокомплит, что бы операции при вводе автокомплита выводились во всплывающей подсказке.Для этого в адаптере методом generationOfAutocompleteText:

```
private void generationOfAutocompleteText() {
    Cursor cursor = sqlDB.query(DBHelper.TABLE_DOWNL_OPERATION,null,null,null,null,null,null,null);
if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
    int indexOfFIOColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.OPERATION_DOWNLOADED);
    do {
        operationns.add(cursor.getString(indexOfFIOColumn));
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    cursor.close();
}
}
```

я заполняю в getView автокомплит:

```
//generationOfAutocompleteText(); //добавляются данные в AutoComplete
ArrayAdapter<String> adapterOperations = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, operationns);
holder.operationsAutocomplete.setAdapter(adapterOperations);
```

но при прогоне на устройстве вылетает. Автокомплит и листвью у меня рабочие, вся проблема в методе generationOfAutocompleteText, а точнее методе query. Причем пробывал на других таблицах, подставлял ихнии столбцы название таблицы в данный метод и все работало, а данная таблица - нет. Даже создал столбец айди в данной таблицы, но естевственно, безрезультатно. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как исправить query, дабы автокомплит работал?

updated:

> 23630/ru.work.jpg.strelchm.alrino_photographyofwork E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main work.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: downloaded_operations (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM downloaded_operations

такая ошибка в логе... причем execSQL прописал разграничивая для всех таблиц, но первую почему-то он пропускает, а остальные такими ошибками обкладывает...

Comment: стектрейс при падении приложения добавьте в вопрос

Comment: 23630/ru.work.jpg.strelchm.alrino_photographyofwork E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                 work.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: downloaded_operations (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM downloaded_operations

Comment: такая ошибка в логе... причем execSQL прописал разграничивая для всех таблиц, но первую почему-то он пропускает, а остальные такими ошибками обкладывает...

Comment: вы добавили остальные таблицы позже, чем первую?

Comment: Чтобы метод `onUpgrade()` сработал и добавленные таблицы попали в структуру БД,  значение `DATABASE_VERSION` нужно увеличить( сделать = 2, например) и так же увеличивать при любых изменениях в структуре БД.

Comment: параллельно с Вами удалил бд и заново все пошло! Спасибо за помощь!